# How to add link to this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, href

This is the full javascript for read more link of post summary-

`<script type='text/javascript'>`
`//<![CDATA[`
`function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){`
    `if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)`
    `{`
        `var s = strx.split("<");`
        `for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){`
            `if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){`
                `s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length);`
            `}`
        `}`
        `strx =  s.join("");`
    `}`
    `chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2;`
    `while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++;`
    `strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1);`
    `return strx+'...';`
`}`

`function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){`
    `var div = document.getElementById(pID);`
    `var imgtag = "";`
    `var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");`
    `var summ = summary_noimg;`
       `if(thumbnail_mode == "yes") {`
    `if(img.length>=1) {`
        `imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding-right:10px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>';`
        `summ = summary_img;`
    `}`
    `}`
    **`var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';`**
    `div.innerHTML = summary;`
`}`
`//]]>`
`</script>`
In var summary i tried to add a link like `<a href='http://xyz.com'>read more</a>`  in this way    
`var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '<a href='http://xyz.com'>' + '<span>' + readmore + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</div>';` 
But this is not working. I know little bit javascript. Please help me.

Comment: `+ '<a href=\'http://xyz.com\'>' +` or, even better, `+ '<a href="http://xyz.com">' +` - and where is `readmore` defined?

Comment: What does readmore contains? You didn't delcare it. Check your HTML, you should have an empty a tag: <a href="http://xyz.com"><span></span></a>. Use " not ' for the href attribute.

Comment: enclose your href within double quotes("") or escape the existing single (' ') with a backward slash.like this `'<a href=\'http://xyz.com\'>'`

Comment: <a class='more' expr:href='data:post.url'>